# different using Plugin vs appView.addJavascriptInterface

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova-2.0.0

I want to build a native apps in android using phonegap cordova. I found 2 way to make my html file can comunicate to my java file. I can using appView.addjavascriptInterface or make my java file to be a plugin.
I want to now which way is the best.
What is the diferences using plugin or appView.addJavascriptInterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Cordova Plugin is the recommended approach to expose Java code to the JavaScript layer of your application. Take a look at the [Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) and [Developing a Plugin on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android).

`addJavascriptInterface`is part of Android [WebView API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and it's used inside of [Apache Cordova's Android code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L309). There's at least [one bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987) with Android 2.3 and that method you [can avoid](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L302) by using Apache Cordova's plugin system.

> What is the diferences using plugin or appView.addJavascriptInterface?

The difference is a Cordova Plugin is a higher level abstraction that allows you to consistently expose native code from various platforms (Android, iOS, among others), to the WebView running your JavaScript code. While the `addJavascriptInterface` is an Android-specific method that is part of the WebView API which is used Apache Cordova's Android code.